# How to compare two IEnumerable object and find files which are different and new?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to compare two `IEnumerable<>` object and return a new `IEnumerable<>` object.

I want to compare `newFiles` object with `OriginalFiles` object and do below things:

- Figure out what are new file in `newFiles` object which isn't there in `OriginalFiles` object.
- And the files which are different in `newFiles` and `OriginalFiles` object in terms of data. Meaning those files that got changed between those two objects.

I have md5hash for each of the file so I compare md5hash and figure out what files got changed between `newFiles` and `OriginalFiles` object in terms of data. Below is my code:

```
public IEnumerable<FileConfig> GetNewFiles(IEnumerable<FileConfig> newFiles) =>
from element1 in newFiles
join element2 in this.OriginalFiles
    on element1.Name.ToLowerInvariant() equals element2.Name.ToLowerInvariant()
    into g
where !g.Any() || !element1.MD5Hash.SequenceEqual(g.First().MD5Hash)
select new FileConfig
{
    Name = element1.Name,
    Timestamp = element1.Timestamp,
    MD5Hash = element1.MD5Hash,
};
```

I am noticing a bug where if I have some new file in `newFiles` object that isn't there in `OriginalFiles` object then in my final output I don't have that new file in it? Somehow it's not detecting that new file.

For example if `newFiles` object has 11 files and `OriginalFiles` object has 10 files and all those 10 files are same with 10 files in `newFiles` object but there is one new one in `newFiles` object then it doesn't detect that in my final output. Is there anything wrong I am doing in my above code?

Comment: Looks like you need [left join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) here

Comment: Isn’t the code doing left outer join already?

Comment: As a side note, I would prefer to test for equality using the [`StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase) method. AFAIK comparing two `ToLowerInvariant` values is less robust and less efficient.

Comment: Am I not doing left join already? I am not understanding what is wrong I am doing here? @GuruStron

Comment: What is the type of `MD5Hash`?

Comment: @NetMage It is `byte[] MD5Hash`

Comment: Why are you creating a new `FileConfig` instead of just returning `element1`?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me (if not the most efficient - consider a `Dictionary<string,FileConfig>` for `OriginalFiles`) so I think something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a list of mismatches. You want a list of the new files, excluding any file that exists in your old file list with the same name and hash.

```
public IEnumerable<FileConfig> GetNewFiles(IEnumerable<FileConfig> newFiles) =>
    newFiles
        .Where
        (
            n => !this.OriginalFiles.Any( o => 
                   o.Name.Equals(n.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                   o.MD5hash.SequenceEqual(n.MD5Hash)
                )
        )
        .Select
        (
            n => new FileConfig
            {
                Name = n.Name,
                Timestamp = n.Timestamp,
                MD5Hash = n.MD5Hash
            }
        );
```